# How to autoincrement the id without identity?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm trying do to a bulk insert from another table in sql server. My query is currently like that :

```
INSERT INTO Table1(Id, Value)
SELECT ??, Value
FROM Table2;
```

Now, my problem is obviously by what I replace `??`. `Id` is an integer column without an identity property. I would like that for each inserted row, `Id` take the current `max(Id) + 1`.

Can I do that directly in my insert command?

Comment: Don't do this to yourself. Why do you want "roll your own" identity. There are so many pitfalls of trying to do this yourself it is staggering. Think about things like concurrency. Why not use identity? They already figured out all the challenges.

Comment: @SeanLange I agree with you to 100% and I would gladly take the identity route but unfortunately it's not an option.

Comment: Why is it not an option?

Comment: Are you really using sql 2000? If so, the only real way to do this is with an identity.

Comment: Sean seem right, for SQL 2000,  the only other way around identity I see is a while loop. But in these case, that isn't called "bulk insert" anymore and performance would be slow for tons of data.

Comment: Create a temp table with ID as identity and do a bulk insert into the temp table. Then insert the data from temp table your table.

Comment: @kar that is the solution I posted few minutes ago.

Comment: Yes SQL-Server 2000...

Comment: Oops our post might have collided in cyber space. Your answer was close enough to mine except I was not intending to a join from Table2 in the last insert, instead insert the Table2 to the temp table and copy it over.

Comment: I used the join in the last insert in case he has multiple values. If so, it would become heavy the write down on disk all the values in the temp table before writing them back in table1.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the requirement that you can not make the key field an identity with an explanation.  Also specify if you have complete control on the inserts into this table or are there other processes adding to it.  And how might those other processes be choosing keys for the ID or is that unknown?

Comment: There are many reasons why using an IDENTITY setting is NOT an option. In cases where the legacy software is already creating new IDs automatically, and if you change the column to IDENTITY TRUE, it will crash those VB6 programs!

Answer (score 6):

If you were using a newer version of SQL Server (2008+) you could try [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
DECLARE @BASE INT 
SET @BASE = (SELECT IsNull(MAX(ID),0) FROM Table1)

INSERT INTO Table1(Id, Value)
SELECT 
    @BASE + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Value) ID, 
    Value
FROM Table2;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0d26c/2)

Since you are using SQL Server 2000, you could try like bellow:

```
DECLARE @BASE INT 
SET @BASE = (SELECT IsNull(MAX(ID),0) FROM Table1)

INSERT INTO Table1(Id, Value)
SELECT 
   @BASE +  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 AS i2 WHERE i2.Value <= a.Value),
   a.Value
FROM Table2 a
```

**But it will only works if Value in Table2 is unique**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0d26c/1)

If Table2 has a primary key (field `PK`), then you could use:

```
INSERT INTO Table1(Id, Value)
SELECT 
   @BASE +  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 AS i2 WHERE i2.PK <= a.PK),
   a.Value
FROM Table2 a
```

Comment: Would be better if you could use an integer primary key instead of Value in your where clause. This since Value is probably data he don't have much control over.

Comment: I don´t know if Table2 has a real primary key. But it is certainly better if it has, I agree.

Comment: @AXMIM, I have updated my answer with your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one wicked way.
We create a temp table with identity to generate new ids. This way we avoid the while loop.

```
DECLARE @CurrentMaxID   INT,
        @DynamicQuery   NVARCHAR(MAX)

--TODO : Acquired table lock here on table1

SELECT @FirstNextID = ISNULL(MAX(Id), 0)
FROM Table1 --WITH(TABLOCK)



CREATE TABLE #TempTableWithID(  Table2Id        INT,
                                Table1FuturId   INT IDENTITY(1, 1))

INSERT INTO #TempTableWithID(Table2Id)
SELECT Id   --Here we use identity to generate table1 futur id
FROM Table2


INSERT INTO Table1(Id, value)
SELECT  Temp.Table1FuturId + @FirstNextID,
        Table2.Value
FROM Table2 
INNER JOIN #TempTableWithID AS Temp ON Table2.Id = Temp.Table2Id

--TODO : release table lock here on table1


DROP TABLE #TempTableWithID
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this should work.

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl1 (ID int, Value float)
CREATE TABLE #tbl2 (ID int, Value float)
INSERT INTO #tbl2 values (4, 2.0)
INSERT INTO #tbl2 values (8, 3.0)
INSERT INTO #tbl2 values (6, 4.0)
INSERT INTO #tbl1 values (1,1.0)
INSERT INTO #tbl1 values (3,3)
INSERT INTO #tbl1 values (9,3)

/*meat and potatoes start*/

INSERT INTO #tbl1(Id, Value)
SELECT (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM #tbl1) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Value) ID, Value
FROM #tbl2;

/*meat and potatoes end*/

Select * From #tbl1

drop table #tbl1
drop table #tbl2
```

Comment: The other issue here is what happens when two people are executing this code at the same time?

Comment: @SeanLange - Modified the answer.  Still definitely doesn't account for two people executing simultaneously.  I agree that Identity would be preferable.

Comment: If the OP correctly tagged then this won't work either because they tagged sql 2000 and ROW_NUMBER didn't exist until 2005. It is about the best you could do though. The no identity rule is one that we see all the time and there is usually not a valid reason for it.

Comment: Scratch that.  he's on sql 2000

Answer (score -1):

Why not [IDENT_CURRENT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx) ?

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('yourtablename')
```

It gives you the next ID reference. But this only works if the ID column has IDENTITY turned on.

OR you can try a `SEQUENCE` and the [NEXT VALUE FOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE Test.TestTable  
     (CounterColumn int PRIMARY KEY,  
    Name nvarchar(25) NOT NULL) ;   
GO  

INSERT Test.TestTable (CounterColumn,Name)  
    VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR Test.CountBy1, 'Syed') ;  
GO  

SELECT * FROM Test.TestTable;   
GO
```